# On RabbitMq Restart Consumers do Not Consume

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-rabbit

We are using Spring Rabbit to produce and consume messages from the same application, however, we noticed that when RabbitMq is restarted, the queues continue to grow until we restart Tomcat.  Initially, we thought that having a high availability queue would cure this, but it has not.  Here is the messaging.xml for the Spring-Rabbit configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.3.xsd">

    <!--  RabbitMQ -->
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory" addresses="${rabbitMq.hostName}" username="${rabbitMq.userName}" password="${rabbitMq.password}" virtual-host="${rabbitMq.vHost}" />
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>

    <!-- RabbitMQ Template -->
    <rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" message-converter="messageConverter" exchange="${rabbitMq.myExchange}" />

    <!-- RabbitMQ Exchange and Binding Definition -->
    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="${rabbitMq.yEmxchange}">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding key="${rabbitMq.routing.key.events}" queue="${rabbitMq.queue.events.name}"/>
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>

    <!-- RabbitMQ Queue Definitions -->
    <rabbit:queue name="${rabbitMq.queue.events.name}" >
        <rabbit:queue-arguments>
            <entry key="x-ha-policy" value="all"/>
        </rabbit:queue-arguments>
    </rabbit:queue>

    <!-- Listeners -->
    <rabbit:listener-container id="listener" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" concurrency="3" max-concurrency="5" requeue-rejected="false">
        <rabbit:listener ref="eventNotificationAdapter" queues="${rabbitMq.queue.events.name}" priority="${rabbitMq.queue.events.priority}" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>

    <!-- Message Listener Adapters -->
    <bean id="eventNotificationAdapter" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
        <constructor-arg name="delegate" ref="eventConsumer"/>
        <constructor-arg name="messageConverter" ref="messageConverter"/>
        <property name="defaultListenerMethod" value="process"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageConverter" class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter"/>

</beans>
```

Here's the simple consumer:

```
@Component("eventConsumer")
public class EventQueueConsumer {

    @Autowired
    EventsClient eventsClient;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventQueueConsumer.class);

    public void process(MyEvent myEvent) {
        logger.info("processing myEvent: {}", myEvent);
        try{
            eventsClient.sendEvent(myEvent);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred trying to send event.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Based on this configuration, would anyone happen to know why the queues continue to grow and not be consumed after restarting RabbitMq server?  We always have to restart the webserver where the app is running (Tomcat) to make it start consuming again.

Comment: What version of Spring AMQP are you using? The container should attempt to reconnect every 5 seconds (by default, but can be altered with the `recoveryInterval` on the container). `11:57:52.131 WARN  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-13][org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` - you should see one of these every 5 seconds until the broker comes back up.

Comment: Hi Gary, I'm using org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:1.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: Do you see anything like that in the log? If not, then I suspect the thread is hung somewhere in your code. You can use jstack to take a thread dump to see what the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-nn` thread is doing.

Comment: @GaryRussell I'm not seeing anything like that in the logs.

Comment: So `jstack` is your friend the next time you see a hang.